# Problem 1.70 of Megginson's "An Introduction to Banach Space Theory"

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose that $ 1 < p < \infty $ and that $T$ is a linear operator from $L_p[0, 1]$
into itself with the property that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $L_p[0, 1]$ that
converges almost everywhere to some $ f \in L_p[0, 1]$, then $(Tf_n)$ converges
almost everywhere to $T_f$. Prove that $T$ is bounded.

> **Attempted proof**
>
> This seems to follow immediately from the Uniform Boundedness Principle, which states:
>
> *Let $F$ be a nonempty family of bounded linear operators
>   from a Banach space $X$ into a normed space $Y$. If  $\sup \{ \lVert Tx \rVert : T \in  F \}$ is
>   finite for each $x$ in $X$, then $ \sup \{ \lVert T \rVert : T \in  F \} $ is finite.*
>
> In our problem, we merely need to consider $L_p[0, 1]$ as the Banach space $X$ and the result follows. $\quad \square$

It's either this simple, or I'm missing a point.

Comment: While you're asking for proof verification, which is slightly different, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325939/tlp-rightarrow-lp-is-bounded-if-it-respects-almost-everywhere-convergence?rq=1) is the same (just let $f_n' = f_n-f$).

Comment: It is not clear how you are applying BanachSteinhaus here. In one case you have ae. pointwise convergence, in the other you are dealing with norms. The closed graph theorem seems like a better fit.

Comment: You are missing something: you have only one operator, and if you insist on treating it as a "family of bounded linear operators", then you are obviously assuming (that it is bounded) that which you need to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed Graph Theorem is closer. But we need to fulfil the premises of Closed Graph Theorem:

We need to prove that, if $(f_{n})\subseteq L^{p}[0,1]$ converges in $L^{p}[0,1]$ to $f$ and $(T(f_{n}))$ converges to $g$ in $L^{p}[0,1]$, then $g=T(f)$.

Note that $L^{p}[0,1]$ convergence implies a pointwise a.e. convergence of a subsequence. So, we have, say, $f_{n_{k}}\rightarrow f$ a.e. for some subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$. Then by assumption we know that $T(f_{n_{k}})\rightarrow T(f)$ a.e.

For this subsequence $(T(f_{n_{k}}))$, it still holds true that $T(f_{n_{k}})\rightarrow g$ in $L^{p}[0,1]$. So, we have, say, $T(f_{n_{k_{l}}})\rightarrow g$ a.e. for some subsequence $(T(f_{n_{k_{l}}}))$. Since it still holds true that $T(f_{n_{k_{l}}})\rightarrow T(f)$ a.e., we conclude that $g=T(f)$ a.e.

Under the a.e. identification in $L^{p}[0,1]$, then $g=T(f)$, the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for the commnt but why did you assume $(f_n)$ is convergent in $L^p$? The hypothesis of the problem assumes only a.e convergence. Also, further down the post, you claimed that it's still true that $(T(f_{n_k}))$ converges in $L^p$ to $g$. Why's that?

Comment: That is the assumption of Closed Graph Theorem, the so called $X$ and $Y$ are $L^{p}$, and in the Closed Graph Theorem, one assumes first that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $X$ and $T(f_{n})\rightarrow g$ in $Y$.

Comment: Now $T(f_{n})\rightarrow g$ in $Y$, then all its subsequences also converge to $g$ in $Y$, then $T(f_{n_{k}})$ is one of its subsequences.

Comment: Suddenly everything is all clear! Excellent answer as always.